# How to get only date from full date time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello I am getting one date from backend like this-

```
const date = Tue Jul 26 2022 20:58:08 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)
```

From this date need only `2022-07-26` format

Can you help me. I am using momentjs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using momentjs, try using their formats:

```
moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

It should return this value - 2022-07-09

Comment: I need this format `2022-07-09`

Comment: Use ```moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about momentjs but you can easily do this in vanilla

```
var dtDate = new Date()
var sDate = dtDate.toISOString().split("T")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it with a custom Moment format:

```
date.format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do with pure Javascript easily as code below:

```js
const date = new Date();

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('bn-BD')) // => '৯/৭/২০২২'
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
let databaseDateString = 'Tue Jul 26 2022 20:58:08 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)';
const formatedDate = new Date(Date.parse(databaseDateString)).toISOString().split('T')[0];
console.log(formatedDate);
```

[![

```js
let databaseDateString = 'Tue Jul 26 2022 20:58:08 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)';
const formatedDate = new Date(Date.parse(databaseDateString)).toISOString().split('T')[0];
console.log(formatedDate);
```

][1]][1]